# Problems with IPMI on Fedora

Tags: ipmi

I would like to monitoring the consumption of energy of my notebook.
I like of IPMI and installed.
After install, I loaded all modules and run the ipmitool command and show the follow error:

```
ipmitool -I open chassis power status
Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory
Unable to get Chassis Power Status**
```

The output dmesg is:

```
ipmi message handler version 39.2
ipmi device interface
IPMI System Interface driver.
ipmi_si: probing via hardcoded address
ipmi_si: Adding hardcoded-specified kcs state machine<
ipmi_si: Trying hardcoded-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
```

Anybody can help me?
Thank you!!

Comment: This is not a programming question, therefore off-topic.

Comment: Welcome! Try to post the question here http://unix.stackexchange.com/ seems to be more related to drivers.

Answer (score 0):

IPMItool can only check server power which equipped with one physical controller(BMC) which have kcs channel with i/o address 0xa2 to communicate between PCH and BMC. This is what dmesg indicated. Notebook should not be able to make it....